# Back propagation algorithm for time delay neural network in matlab

Tags: algorithm, matlab, neural-network

I'm using a time delay neural network in matlab and I want to train it with different training algorithm. I use a lot of these algorithms for example particle swarm optimization, levenberg marquardt, quasi newton and ... . Now I want to use back propagation but I can't use **traingd**  function because back propagation for time delay neural network is different from feed forward betwork. Can any body please tell me is there any function in matlab for train TDNN with back propagation or not?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

From [mathworks](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/nnet/ug/design-time-series-time-delay-neural-networks.html):

> One nice feature of the FTDNN is that it does not require dynamic
>   backpropagation to compute the network gradient. This is because the
>   tapped delay line appears only at the input of the network, and
>   contains no feedback loops or adjustable parameters. For this reason,
>   you will find that this network trains faster than other dynamic
>   networks.

Use *timedelaynet(inputDelays,hiddenSizes,trainFcn)*

[Example](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/nnet/ref/timedelaynet.html):

```
[X,T] = simpleseries_dataset;
net = timedelaynet(1:2,10)
[Xs,Xi,Ai,Ts] = preparets(net,X,T)
net = train(net,Xs,Ts,Xi,Ai);
view(net)
Y = net(Xs,Xi,Ai);
perf = perform(net,Ts,Y)
```